# Is it necessary to define type again in useState if an interface is already used?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, interface

Consider this code:

`IAppStateProps.ts`:

```
import {INoteProps} from "./INoteProps";

export interface IAppStateProps {
  notesData: INoteProps[];
}
```

then use it here:
`useAppState.ts`:

```
import {INoteProps} from "./interfaces/INoteProps";
import {IAppStateProps} from "./interfaces/IAppStateProps";
export const useAppState = (): IAppStateProps => {
  const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState<INoteProps[]>([]);
  ...more code
  return {
    notesData
  }
};
```

My question is, since I defined the return type of `useAppState` to be `IAppStateProps`, and it knows that `notesData` should return `INoteProps[]`, is it necessary to define the return type again in `const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState<INoteProps[]>([]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since I defined the return type of useAppState to be IAppStateProps, and it knows that notesData should return INoteProps[], is it necessary to define the return type again in const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState<INoteProps[]>([]);?

Yes. TypeScript can't infer it in the direction you're describing. If you leave the type argument off the call to `useState` and you use an empty array like that as the intial value, TypeScript will infer `never[]` as the type, which means you wouldn't be able to call `setNotesData` with real data:

```typescript
// Stand-in for `INoteProps`, since it's not defined in the question
interface INoteProps {
    something: string;
}
// ...
export const useAppState = (): IAppStateProps => {
    const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNotesData([
            {something: "cool"} // <== Error: Type '{ something: string; }' is 
                                // not assignable to type 'never'. (2322)
        ])
    }, []);

    return {
        notesData
    };
};
```

[Error on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAERTo42sDcAUH2AA7fFDJd0cAJIA5CPgAKTMKkR84GuKmboYAC2EBzAFxaYUI-1oDho8VUlSAgmDDY86JRBVqNQ+eioACJ4OKayAV4qANoAulYC6AAekLBwVBBCqPBo6C5uuPhwALxwABQAlOH57orKqsUAfL6aGVnw0f74waFEGDBy3SG4sSXEWIXoZXEV-OqaueSUNGWVJc0I85qa-YOBwzjTW9snCNogugZCJmwZEAA2rPQA9M9wADzFpSRQTFCmABUAJ5gSQAciQ50uRlM2Qs1x4cFoYLgwFUXTgOFQqGAhiEOAARvdJDAIHAYCDwUJ0AA3dBQMEAOjKACYAMwslkVY7bWLc7a0IgzObbDgwZBQIQtE5wLr7ULHWhWHhAA)

**If** you want, you can infer it the other way, though, by leaving off the return type annotation on `useAppState`:

```typescript
export const useAppState = () => {
    const [notesData, setNotesData] = useState<INoteProps[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNotesData([
            {something: "cool"} // <== Works
        ])
    }, []);

    return {
        notesData
    };
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAogGZnoDG8AvnGVBCHAERTo42sDcAUH2AA7fFDJd0cAJIA5CPgAKTMKkR84GuKmboYAC2EBzAFxaYUI-1oDho8VUlSAgmDDY86JRBVqNQ+eioACJ4OKayAV4qANoAulYC6AAekLBwVBBCqPBo6C5uuPhwALxwABQAlCUAfL6aGVnw0f74waFEGDByrSG4sSXEWIXoADwRisqocdVlcRX86pq55JQ0ZZU1dZqand2BvTizi9sniNogugZCJmwZEAA2rPQA9M9wI8WlAOrQANaoxxOsQqgNoRDmC22HBgyCgQi2Jxa+1CoKsPCAA)

TypeScript will infer the return type as `{ notesData: INoteProps[]; }`. Since TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the *shape* of types) not *nominal* (based on the names of types), that's the same as `IAppStateProps`.

You may not want to do that, though, since an erroneous edit that accidentally changes the return type of the function wouldn't be caught by TypeScript. In practice, I find inferring the return type is fine for really short, simple functions, but for anything beyond that I need the safety net of specifying what the return should be so edits accidentally changing it get caught early. Your mileage may vary. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly the question. No, you don't need to specify it.
When you invoke useAppState it should return an object that has property notesData which is an array.